# The number of outputs in feed forward ANN

Tags: matlab, neural-network, feed-forward

The number of outputs (number of neurons in output layer) in feed forward neural network can be more than 2 (such as 3)?

Comment: please what do you mean about the outputs? do you mean the neurons in the InferoTemporal layer? can you explain to me more details in order to help you

Comment: A "Feed Forward Neural Network" has an input layer, hidden layers, and an output layer. I worked by ANN that had been output layer with one neuron.Now, my question is: can output layer be have 3 neurons?In other words, can we predict 3 variables by ANN, simultaneously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neural Network can have **arbitrary** number of output neurons, 2, 3, or even 2131.

Comment: I would love to see the reason for a negative vote for this answer.